# DateTime.Now in Blazor Webassembly is null

Tags: c#, blazor-client-side

I have this code:

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now; // null
    decimal noon = 0m;
    int dayOfYear = now.DayOfYear; // reports 98, correct
    bool isAM = false;
    if (dayOfYear >= 80 && dayOfYear <= 260)
    {
        noon = 13m;
        int h = now.Hour; // 0 (should be 15)          
        isAM = now.Hour >= 13 ? false : true; // true (should be false)
    }
```

in Blazor webassembly in a component, When I debug, While 'now' variable is null the 'dayOfYear' variable correctly shows 98, But 'now.Hour' is 0, And the correct computer time is 3:30 PM, Why 'now' variable is null? And how it correctly reports dayOfYear 98? why Hour is 0!? I am using Blazor 3.2 using its new debugging capability.

**Update**:
The hour is correct, Only the DateTime object's 'null' value put me in doubt as the following screenshot shows:

[image]

Comment: The `now` variable can't possibly be null - it's a non-nullable value type. This sounds like a debugger issue.

Comment: I also don't understand why retrieving time parts of a DateTime object don't work, I think it is because the Local time has PM and AM in local language that I configured my computer.

Comment: "Don't work" is pretty vague - we don't know how you're examining these values at all, and that seems to be entirely separate (and incompatible) with the value being null. I suggest you change your question to add some diagnostics that *display* `now.Hour`, `now.Minute`, `now.DayOfYear` etc, along with sample output (and what the current time is when you run it). (But no, `DateTime.Hour` should not be affected by formatting.)

Comment: Note that an hour of 12 is usually regarded as PM. There are 12 hours of AM (0-11) and 12 hours of PM (12-23).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem the other day.
At this time Blazor Wasm doesn't contain any time zone info and local time zone is always UTC.
However, there is a fix available in order to get the right time zone info.
Check this out: [Blazor WebAssembly App (client-side) Time Zone Kit](https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.TimeZoneKit)

Answer (score -1):

Solved my problem using this code, Maybe local Am Pm is the problem:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date; // here
    int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour; // here       
    double noon = 0;
    int dayOfYear = now.DayOfYear; // here
    bool isAM = false;
    if (dayOfYear >= 80 && dayOfYear <= 260)
    {
        noon = 13;
        int h = hour; 
        isAM = hour >= 13 ? false : true; // here
    }
```

Comment: 12:35pm will have an Hour of 12, but it's still pm. 12:35am will have an hour of 0. Your logic should be `isAM = hour < 12`.

Comment: Additionally, this answer certainly has no bearing on the claim that `DateTime.Now` is null....